# Connect Arduino Uno to server using oneM2M platform

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno that doesn't have any Wi-Fi. After putting the sensor there, I've found out that it is quiet impossible to connect to localhost for oneM2M platform.

Is there any possibility that I can connect to localhost using just the blue cable below which will also being used for uploading the code? Any help will be much appreciated!

[image: Sensor on breadboard and Uno]

Comment: there was an attempt to make TCP over Serial. I don't know if it works. https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SerialIP

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it without a special software running on the computer. I mean special as in someone will need to write it since there likely isn't something available that you can find.

The most practical solution is to either use an ethernet shield on the Uno. Or use a board like the Wemos D1 Mini (an ESP8266 based board) that can do Wifi. It can run under the Arduino platform. And they are dirt cheap.

https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1:d1_mini

https://wiki.wemos.cc/doku.php

https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1_mini_shields:dht_shield

Comment: So what you mean here is it is impossible to connect to server without the wifi thingy (ESP8266) ?

Comment: Wifi or ethernet. Ethernet is a wired connection, it would go into a router. I prefer WiFi as it is more convenient. And not all that hard to do. There are a lot of examples that can be the foundation for what you want to access.